# my rails db:migrate isnt working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i tried running rake bd:migrate but it gave me an error and told me to run rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development instead but it gave me bunch of errors

```
C:\Sites\seekhostel.com>rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20180311182801 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Sites/seekhostel.com/db/migrate/20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

[image]

i would love to know why it did so and how to fix it

Comment: The error is there "_SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email_". What's on that migration?

Comment: you trying to add column which already exists in schema

Comment: so how can i fix it pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mi rails db:migrate is giving me some errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225963/mi-rails-dbmigrate-is-giving-me-some-errors)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at error message I suspect two things happened here:

1. You already had `users` table (because new migration has `change_table(:users)`, not `create_table(:users)` - devise generator recognize that)
2. You ran `$ rails generate devise` command and you didn't inspect autogenerated migration file.

You were supposed to remove line

```
t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
```

from `20180311182801_add_devise_to_users.rb` file

Comment: actually, had a user table bed=fore but had some issues before i was told to try devise

Comment: would it be safe to delete all migrations and restart with devise

Comment: @OmiyeraDamilola You don't have to delete all migrations. Only change the one generated by devise and run `rake db:migrate` again. 

But if you delete all migration files and start from scratch you will need to create database again using `rake db:drop db:create` (which means destroying all records)